# the provided key element does not match the schema - java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Not sure what the issue is here.This is my database on Amazon DynamoDb. I keep getting the issue of the provided key element does not match the schema.Ive done debuggind and Im sure all of the values are set, but not sure why this issue is coming up. Am I missing something?

[image]

This is the snippet of code where I actually try to add into the db

```
final Job job = new Job();
job.setDescription(txtDescription.getText().toString());
job.setType("Job entry");
job.setPrice(500);
job.setDate((new Date()).getTime());
job.setId("1");
job.setPosterID("poster");
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ActivityMain.getAWSClient(getActivity()));
            mapper.save(job);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Comment: You'll have better chances of getting help if you post code as formatted text instead of images

Answer (score 2):

pay attention to the @DynamoDBHashKey and @DynamoDBAttribute in the object class.
don't confuse between them .the first is for the key of the schema, and the second is for the regular attributes. even if you try to set only the key and don't use the  other attributes,and then try to upload it to dynamodb, you will get an exception. of course it's relevant to the other "@" tags you can attach to the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a mismatch between your data model and the actual table in DynamoDB. Make sure that the key defined in your 'Job' class (partition key and optionally sort key) matches the exact name and type of the table in DynamoDB (defined in your class by the `@DynamoDBTable` attribute). For example, if you executed the `save` operation using the data model below, and the table `ProductCatalog` had a partition key `Id` of type `string`, DynamoDB would generate the same exception as the data model defines the key as `Integer`:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="ProductCatalog")
public static class CatalogItem {
   private Integer id;
   private String title;

   //Partition key
   @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="Id")
   public Integer getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Title")
  public String getTitle() { return title; }    
  public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

}
```